# how to broadcast my voice From iPhone to Web using shoutcast/icecast

Tags: ios, xcode, video-streaming, broadcastreceiver, audio-streaming

how to broadcast my voice From iPhone to Web shout cast/ice cast , basically I have seen many of the code snippets just like Audio Streamer (in this code audio streaming through URL) , now I want to stream (broadcast) my sound from iPhone to web. through shout cast/ ice cast, how can I do it..

Please help me in this situation .

Comment: many of the people said that use libshout  library but how can I use this library in iPhone ... need help.